# WPF Update progress bar on dialog form

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, progress-bar

I have a ProgressBar on a form which I want to show as a dialog when the parent form is performing a long operation.

The ProgressWindow is simple:

The constructor takes in the max value and I have an increment method.

```
public ProgressWindow(int count)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fileProgressBar.Maximum = count;
}

public void IncremntProgress()
{
    fileProgressBar.Value++;
}
```

On the parent I create an instance:

```
ProgressWindow progressWindow = new ProgressWindow(listOfFiles.Count);
progressWindow.Show();
```

I then run a large operation and I want to update the progressbar:

```
foreach (var file in listOfFiles)
{
    ....
    progressWindow.IncremntProgress();
}

progressWindow.Close();
```

This works but I'd like the form to be a dialog and the progress bar doesn't refresh correctly.

Is there a better way of updating a progress bar on a dialog window?

Comment: Has you `ProgressBar`an Min and Max Value on XAML? `<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Name="fileProgressBar" />`

Comment: If you run large operation in the UI thread, then for a whole duration of `foreach` you are not letting UI to draw/update anything. Three approaches: 1) move operation into separate thread and invoke (best) 2) display progress using window created in another thread (might be good if you have to invoke too many changes to UI) 3) call `Application.DoEvents()` periodically inside the loop (not recommended).

Comment: Yes, I have set the Min and Max values

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what "doesn't refresh correctly" actually means here but you should run the "large operation" on a background thread and update any UI elements including the ProgressBar back on the UI thread:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    //...
    foreach (var file in listOfFiles)
    {
        //...
        progressWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=> progressWindow.IncremntProgress()));
    }
}).ContinueWith(task => 
{
    progressWindow.Close();
}, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The UI thread cannot both update the ProgressBar and run your operation/loop simultaneously.

Comment: This is great but is there anyway to make the progressWindow Modal?